# rails second development environment console output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, output, environment

I have a rails app, when I run it with -e development it prints on the console normally.

I created a second environment "development2" copied all the files that describe the original development and renamed them(development.rb -> development2.rb, yml files etc.).

Now when I run the app under -e development2, everything works as expected, except that there is no output on the console. Why is that and how can I change it?

Comment: How are you running it?  Is it `rails s -e development2`?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question directly, but i would always have a seperate tab tailing the log file, with `tail -f log/development.log`, rather than using the server output.

Comment: Yes, I'm running it with "rails s -e development2?", I know I can use the log file tailing, but I was wondering why one worked and the other didn't.

Comment: Does the tailing the log work then?  This is a total guess but maybe `rails s` also simply tails the log for its output, but for some reason it's looking for the wrong log file to tail.

Comment: tailing the log file works, printing on the console also works.